# NodeJS - How does connection.rollback() work with async.parallel

Tags: node.js

I'm totally new to nodejs. I would like to ask your expertise regarding for error handling using `connection.beginTransaction();` with this sample code.

```
connection.beginTransaction(function(){
    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            connection.query('INSERT INTO SUBJECT.PROJECT (Name, Score) VALUES (?,?)',
                            ['Drake', '85']
                            , function(error){
                                //if(error)
                                //    connection.rollback();
                                callback(error);
                            });
        },
        function(callback){
            connection.query(someUpdateQuery, someValues,
                             function(error){
                                //if(error)
                                //    connection.rollback();                                    
                                callback(error);
                             });
        }
    ], function(error){
            var msg;
            if(error) {
                connection.rollback();
                msg = 'Error! ' + error;
            }
            else {
                connection.commit();
                msg = 'Success';
            }
            res.json(msg);
    });

});
```

- With this sample code, Is this doable?
- Every connection.query has `connection.rollback()` in `if(error)`, can I remove `connection.rollback()` in each 
  connection.query and rely in the last function instead to handle the
  `connection.rollback()`? - will it rollback all *(lets say)* 10 inserting query functions then the 5th 1 got the error.
- Sorry, I don't know much,. thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - you can remove the rollback statements of the individual queries and rely on the one in the `async.parallel` callback. Your code would look something like this:

```
connection.beginTransaction(function () {
  async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
      connection.query('INSERT INTO SUBJECT.PROJECT (Name, Score) VALUES (?,?)',
        ['Drake', '85']
        , callback);
    },
    function (callback) {
      connection.query(someUpdateQuery, someValues, callback);
    }
  ], function (error) {
    var msg;
    if (error) {
      connection.rollback();
      msg = 'Error! ' + error;
    }
    else {
      connection.commit();
      msg = 'Success';
    }
    res.json(msg);
  });
});
```

This works because non of the commands will be committed to the database until you call `connection.commit()` in the final callback. One thing you might want to look at is whether the `commit` and `rollback` methods are asynchronous, i.e. they expect you to pass a callback to them. If so your code as it is will run `res.json` *before* the transaction has been committed or rolled back.

Comment: Good day sir @MrWillihog, thank you so much for your quick reply,. Saves me hours of trial and errors. As you've said I'll look deeper regarding how to use `commit` and `rollback` methods, then again Thanks!